# Can I get storyboard XML code programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Can I get storyboard XML source code programmatically somehow and send it to server?

For example:

```
let sourceCode = storyboard.getCode()
```

Or maybe can I send the whole file to server and have the server parse it by itself?

Comment: Its just a xml file, you could probably get its contents like any other file ? Have you checked in that direction ? But apart from that, could you please let us know the intent behind this ? Because unlike Android's layout XML file, this is a bit different.

Comment: The plan is to parse it on server and show it on web just like in IB in xcode, i mean all buttons, labels, frames and so on.

Comment: ok ! probably you should be able to do. Just read it as a XML file to get its contents and parse it. You should be good.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can read the content of the storyboard-file if you know its name.

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyStoryboard", withExtension: "storyboard")
let fileURL = NSURL(string: filePath)
do {
    let filecontent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    //submit filecontent to your server
}
catch {/* error handling here */}
```

This will give you the filecontent as a string. If you need to parse it as XML you will need to use some kind of XML-parser like e.g. NSXMLParser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't think this way.